# Julia Plotly doesn't show plot with subplots

Tags: julia, plotly, metaprogramming, subplot

I did some workaround before to achieve wonderful subplots in Julia Plotly, but currently struggling with a more complex problem. There are three ways below that should do the job. draw1 does it perfectly, but not applicable in my situation, draw2 does not, draw3 does in the REPL but otherwise not.

Here is the expected matrix of graphs aka subplots. 
[expected matrix of graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGGl8.png)

draw1 does the job -> expected matrix of graphs appears

```
function draw1()
    [plot([1,1,1]) plot([2,2,2]); plot([3,3,3]) plot([4,4,4])]
end
```

draw2a and draw2b do not, regardless of being called as a function of a module or copied into the REPL

```
function draw2a()
    local mx = [1 2; 3 4]
    local p(i) = plot([i,i,i])
    p.(mx)
end
function draw2b()
    local mx = [1 2; 3 4]
    local p = map(i-> plot([i,i,i]), collect(1:4))
    p[mx]
end
```

REPL does the same for draw2a and draw2b:

```
julia> subplots.draw2()
2×2 Array{PlotlyJS.SyncPlot,2}:
 SyncPlot(data: [
  "scatter with fields type, x, and y"
]
...
followed by the content of the graphs
```

draw3 perfectly does the job if copied into the REPL but does not if called

```
function draw3()
    local p(i) = plot([i,i,i])
    eval(Meta.parse("[p(1) p(2); p(3) p(4)]"))
end
```

if called:

```
julia> subplots.draw3()
ERROR: UndefVarError: p not defined
```

it must be a scope issue

Answer (score 1):

### The fix

The following is a modification of `draw2a` which works (i.e. it shows the expected graph):

```
function draw4()
    local mx = [1 2; 3 4]
    local p(i) = plot([i,i,i])
    matrix_with_plots = p.(mx)
    hvcat((2, 2), matrix_with_plots...)
end
```

To understand why `hvcat` displays the expected graph, we have to step back and understand how `SyncPlot` works.

### How does `SyncPlot` work?

Let's take the `draw1` code:

```
[plot([1,1,1]) plot([2,2,2]); plot([3,3,3]) plot([4,4,4])]
```

The shell processes this code block with the following steps:

1. `plot([1,1,1])` calls `PlotlyJS.plot`, which creates a [`SyncPlot` object](https://github.com/sglyon/PlotlyJS.jl/blob/9869ff18f1cda79799e74491c31ca0a5a7058699/src/display.jl#L4-L9), which contains the plot information and some metadata. The other the calls of the `PlotlyJS.plot` function produce similar objects.
2. `[a b; c d]` is just syntactic sugar for `Base.hvcat((2, 2), a, b, c, d)`. The `(2, 2)` tuple means that a 2x2 matrix shall be created. So the next step is that the Julia shell calls the [Base.hvcat function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.hvcat) with the `(2, 2)` tuple and our plots as parameters: `Base.hvcat((2, 2), sync_plot1, sync_plot2, sync_plot3, sync_plot4)`.
3. **But** (twist!) the `Base.hvcat` function has a method specifically for `SyncPlot` objects, which is defined in [PlotlyJS/utils.jl](https://github.com/sglyon/PlotlyJS.jl/blob/9869ff18f1cda79799e74491c31ca0a5a7058699/src/util.jl#L6-L11):

   ```
   # subplot methods on syncplot
   Base.hcat(sps::SyncPlot...) = SyncPlot(hcat([sp.plot for sp in sps]...))
   Base.vcat(sps::SyncPlot...) = SyncPlot(vcat([sp.plot for sp in sps]...))
   Base.vect(sps::SyncPlot...) = vcat(sps...)
   Base.hvcat(rows::Tuple{Vararg{Int}}, sps::SyncPlot...) =
       SyncPlot(hvcat(rows, [sp.plot for sp in sps]...))
   ```

   This means that instead of executing the general, built-in version of the `Base.hvcat` function and creating a usual `Array`, Julia calls PlotlyJS's own `Base.hvcat` function, which produces a new `SyncPlot` object. This new `SyncPlot` object encapsulates the four previous plots as subplots.
4. When the Julia shell finishes the evaluation of a code block, it will try to display the result. It does that by calling the [`Base.display` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.Multimedia.display) on the return value of the code block.

   In our case, the return value of the code block is the `SyncPlot`, so `Base.display(<our SyncPlot>)` is called.
5. **But** (another twist!) the `Base.display` function has a method specifically for `SyncPlot` objects, which is defined in [PlotlyJS/display.jl](https://github.com/sglyon/PlotlyJS.jl/blob/9869ff18f1cda79799e74491c31ca0a5a7058699/src/display.jl#L152):

   ```
   Base.display(::PlotlyJSDisplay, p::SyncPlot) = display_blink(p::SyncPlot)
   ```

   This means that instead of executing the general, built-in version of the `Base.display` function and printing the data structure to the console, Julia calls PlotlyJS's own `Base.display` function, which opens the AtomShell window and shows the graphs there.

The last point also means that you can call `display` explicitly. The following call opens four windows with four plots:

```
for i in 1:4 display(plot([i, i, i])) end
```

### Why does the `hvcat` call fix the code?

The `matrix_with_plots` variable in `draw4` is a plain Julia matrix containing plots. This is returned by `draw2a`. Therefore when the `display` function is called on it, `display` simply prints the data structure on the console.

By calling `hvcat`, we call PlotlyJS's custom `hvcat`, which creates a `SyncPlot` with four subplots (as opposed to a plain Julia matrix containing four `SyncPlot` objects).